# How to divide blocks of arrays in a loop?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to figure out how to take an array stalls[] and find the middle index of a continuously decreasing size.

In essence, I am taking the middle index of an array, assigning it to the boolean true, *then* taking the new, smaller size of an index and finding the halfway point of *that* (ignoring everything to the right).

In print form, it might look like

```
_ _ _ _ _ X _ _ _ _

_ _ X _ _ X _ _ _ _
```

I can't figure out how to get this to loop correctly. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It sounds like homework. What have you tried?

Comment: show us what you've got so far.

Comment: Variable `left`, `right`, set either of them (depending on how you want the follow the middle index) to `(left + right) / 2`

Comment: @RohitJain he needs to find middle index. if an array that size is 5, middle is 2.

Answer (score 1):

Do:

```
  int begin = 0;
  int end = array_size
  int middle = (end + begin) / 2;


  while( ... )
  {
  // do something
     middle = middle / 2; // break in half
  }
```

...

The code above iterate over the first half, to iterate over the second half you just have to modify the `begin` variable, to:

```
int being = array_size / 2;
```

corresponding to the middle of the array.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit vague as to what you are wanting. But this might get you closer.

```
public class homework
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    new homework();
  }

  public homework()
  {
    boolean[] stalls = new boolean[50];

    int middle = stalls.length/2;

    for (int i = 0; i < stalls.length; i++)
    {
      stalls[middle] = true;
      middle /= 2; 
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < stalls.length; i++)
    {
      if (stalls[i] == true)
      {
        System.out.print("X");
      }
      else
      {
        System.out.print("_");
      }

      System.out.print(" ");
    }

    System.out.println("");
  }
}
```